# Querying by Custom Field in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I've added a custom field/column to the 'task' type in TFS and can populate it as I'm adding new work items without a problem, but it doesn't appear as a field I can query or sort against.

The custom field is specific to this project. It's a simple number.

How can I sort by this field, or at least display it in the results set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

The custom field name was preceded with 'Custom'. Didn't think to run right through the list; just jumped straight to where I'd expect it to be alphabetically.

I blame the time of day/week.